# Having issues with field level validation using simple function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

I am fairly new to coding so forgive me if it is something simple I am missing.

I am trying to validate the First Name field using a simple If statement in the function, but when I test it via live server the form submits without throwing the alert.

```js
function validateForm() {

  var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;

  function firstNameValid() {

    if (firstName == "") {
      alert("First name empty")
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }

  };

  firstNameValid(firstName);

};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <form name="registration" action="page2.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">

    <ul>

      <li>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onsubmit="return firstNameValid(document.registration.fname)"><br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber">
      </li>

    </ul>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

  <script>
    src = "app.js"
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script should be loaded into the page like this…

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

…not like this…

```html
<script>
  src = "app.js"
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Assumed it was something silly like this...

Answer (score 0):

`validateForm` doesn't return anything - you probably just need to change

```
firstNameValid(firstName);
```

to

```
return firstNameValid(firstName);
```

But, I'm a little rusty on when a form does / does not end up submitting, you may need to do

```
function validateForm(e) {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    function firstNameValid() {
        if (firstName == "") {
            alert("First name empty")
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
    return firstNameValid(firstName);
};

<form name="registration" action="page2.html" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" method="GET">
```